# Android Support Library 23.2 - Navigation Drawer and/or Toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

When I use the new Android Support Library 23.2 (specifically `com.android.support:design:23.2.0`), the toolbar used in the Android Studio implementation of Navigation Drawer pushes down the icons and title. Take a look:

[With 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHGWu.png)

[With 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mSkB.png)

My Navigation Drawer implementation is just the one generated by Android Studio, no custom changes.

Any clue how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Toolbar resource file (XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.sqoops.sqoops.activity.TimelineActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_timeline"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please share your toolbar resource file (xml)?

Comment: @GuilhermeP Updated question with the toolbar resource file

Comment: Try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and see.

Comment: This is the cause... I just tested here and it works.. It should fix your issue removing fitsSystemWindows

Comment: Success! removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` did the job! Really thanks!

Comment: @razzledazzle Put your comment in a form of answer... to help people in the future...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `Toolbar` tag should help.

> That’s what the default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows=“true” attribute gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows.

The quote above is from one of Android Development Patterns [blogpost](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec).

Added comment as answer as requested.